# Why is this preg_split not working as I want it to?

Tags: php, regex

I have a preg_split pattern as below:

```
$pattern = '/[, ;:-_.|+#\/]/';
```

I use

```
$pcs = preg_split($pattern, $string);
```

if string is " Hello how are you", then `count($pcs) == 5`.
if string is "Hello how are you", then `count($pcs) == 4`.
if string is " Hello how are you ", then `count($pcs) == 6`.

Does anybody know what the problem is? (I want it to return 4 in all above cases).

My plan is to split a user-inputted string into words simply.
The string entered may contain the characters in the pattern above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your whitespace.  I am going to assume the following:

- "Hello how are you" split results has `$pcs[0] == ''`
- "Hello how are you " split results has `$pcs[0] == ''` and `$pcs[5] == ''`

Since there is white space at the beginning and/or end (depending on the case) your preg_split is going to still create the split between nothing and the first and/or last word.  If you want to avoid this you should run a [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) first before your split.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$pcs = preg_split($pattern, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Read more in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: This solution makes sense, but just to play devil's advocate.. what happens to this string? `' ; '` Wouldn't the return just be an empty array?

Comment: Sure, but see what OP wrote *"My plan is to split a user-inputted string into words simply."* which I think is fitting in that case.